# vertical scrollbar is not working in Android

Tags: javascript, css, html

Verticle scrollbar is not working in Android:

Here is my CSS code:

```
.innerItem {
  height:450px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="innerItem">
  my data:- its paragraph  
</div>
```

Comment: This question really needs a question in it before anyone can seriously answer it.

Comment: Most browsers don't support scrolling on elements like this, because it's usually too fiddly to scroll with your finger in small elements on small screens. What are you trying to attempt?

Comment: Just realized I missed an important word in my previous comment: Most **mobile** browsers...

Answer (score 0):

I am not particularly familiar with android, but try changing to

```
.innerItem {
height:450px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: No it is not working with android version 2.2 , and <3 versions.